# Navigate to same compose from different nested navigation graphs in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am doing nested navigation with the idea of reusing the same composable function from different route following is my approach of doing it.

```
navigation(startDestination = DashboardRoutes.You.route, route = PROFILE) {
  profile(paddingValues, navController) // :: ~ PROFILE
  legal(navController) // :: ~ LEGAL
  myUserProfile(navController, paddingValues) // :: ~ MY USER PROFILE
  myHikesNav(navController, 
       paddingValues, route = DashboardRoutes.You.MyHikes.route) // ** <-- (same composable) ** -->
     // :: ~ ----------------------
     // :: ~ MY TRAILS NESTED GRAPH
     // :: ~ ----------------------
     navigation(
        startDestination = DashboardRoutes.You.Trails.route,
        route = MY_TRAILS_ROUTE
     ) {
         myTrailsNav(navController, paddingValues) // :: MY TRAILS
         myHikesNav(navController, paddingValues) // :: <-- (same composable) MY HIKES  ** -->
      }
```

I am calling `myHikesNav` composable from different nested graphs with different routes is this the right approach to do it. Or there is some better approaches available.

Main reason for saparate navigation is to handle transition from different routes to different routes.